# How to send and receive boundary data of an 1D array with MPI?

Tags: pointers, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, mpi, distributed-computing

Good evening,
i'm trying to fix a problem with this MPI code.

Master can send blocks of 1D array to the slaves but when workers exchange data with neighbours the program crashes.I could argue that it is because I should create a vector-datatype to send just the last element to right and the first element to left.How could i do it?

this is the part of the code that gives me problems:

```
numworkers = numtasks-1;
if (taskid == MASTER) {
         printf("Master\n");
double *Q=malloc(m * n * cell_size *  sizeof(double));
/*Set initial Gauss hump*/ 
for (k=0;k<3;k++)     
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
 for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
  Q(k,i,j) = 4.0;
  }
 }
  printf("gauss done.\n");
  averow = (m*n*cell_size)/numworkers;
  extra = (m*n*cell_size)%numworkers;
  MPI_Type_contiguous(rows, MPI_DOUBLE, &rowtype);!
  MPI_Type_commit(&rowtype);

  printf ("Starting program with %d worker tasks.\n", numworkers);
  printf("Grid size: X= %d  Y= %d  Time steps= %d\n",m,n,STEPS);

  for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++) // Distribute work to workers.
  {rows = (i <= extra) ? averow+1 : averow; 
        if (i == 1) // neighbors
        left = NONE;
     else
        left = i - 1;
     if (i == numworkers)
        right = NONE;
     else
        right = i + 1;
     /*  Now send startup information to each worker  */
     dest = i;
     MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, BEGIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
     MPI_Send(&left, 1, MPI_INT, dest, BEGIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
     MPI_Send(&right, 1, MPI_INT, dest, BEGIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
     MPI_Send(Q,1, rowtype, dest, BEGIN, 
              MPI_COMM_WORLD);
     printf("Sent to task %d: rows= %d offset= %d ",dest,rows,offset);
     printf("left= %d right= %d\n",left,right);
     offset = offset + rows;
  }
   for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++)
  {
     source = i;
     msgtype = DONE;
   MPI_Irecv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);         
   MPI_Irecv(Q, 1,rowtype, source,
              msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
   }
  printf("Solver took\n");
  free(Q);
  MPI_Type_free(&rowtype);
  MPI_Finalize();}

  if (taskid != MASTER) 
  {MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, BEGIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  double *Q =malloc(rows*  sizeof(double));     
  MPI_Recv(&left, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, BEGIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  MPI_Recv(&right, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, BEGIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  MPI_Recv(Q, rows, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, BEGIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   printf("ricevo da master rows %d \n",rows);      
  printf("Task %d received work. Beginning time steps...\n",taskid);
  for (it = 1; it <= numworkers; it++)
  {{if (left != NONE)  //boundary data exchange
     {MPI_Send(Q, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, left,
                 RTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        source = left;
        msgtype = LTAG;
        MPI_Recv(Q, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, source,
                  msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);}
     if (right != NONE)
     {
        MPI_Send(Q, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, right,
                  LTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        source = right;
        msgtype = RTAG;
        MPI_Recv(Q, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, source, msgtype,
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);}
     /* Now call update to update the value of grid points*/ 
   Q=Q+1;
     printf("update fatto."); }
  /* Finally, send my portion of final results back to master */
  MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Send(Q, rows, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, DONE, 
           MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  free(Q); 
  MPI_Type_free(&rowtype); 
  MPI_Finalize();
  }
```

Q is defined as:

```
  #define Q(i,j,k) Q[((k) + n * ((j) + m * (i)))]
```

For debugging:I'm using University server with Putty. How could I debug this program?

Thank you so much,I hope someone will help me!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That much of code looks terrible. Please try to distil it down to a minimal example code that still reproduces the bug, otherwise your question will get voted down and/or closed. On _prima vista_, I spot the following error: `{{if (left != NONE);` The semicolon at the end of the line effectively results in the following block being executed always and not only when the condition is met. Also, passing `&Q` to `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` is wrong since `Q` is pointer itself and should be passed directly. Please use a debugger to find the rest of the problems.

Comment: Good morning Hristo and thank you for advices!I posted a shorter and simpler version of the code,I fixed the errors you reported and it still crashes. Unfortunately I'm using MPI on the university servers with Putty and I really don't know how to debug it.Can you give me an advice? Thank you very much!

Comment: Ask the support or admin of the server which debuggers they have. You must specify which compiler (and its version) you use. Recent versions of GCC have sanitizations, study https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html . You can install a C compiler and MPI on your desktop and try there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Non-Blocking and now it works. The program crashed because tasks didn't receive and send data in the right way.I changed the size of data too,it was another bug that I didn't see.Instead of

```
if (left != NONE)  //boundary data exchange
 {MPI_Send(Q, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, left,
             RTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    source = left;
    msgtype = LTAG;
    MPI_Recv(Q, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, source,
              msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);}
 if (right != NONE)
 {
    MPI_Send(Q, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, right,
              LTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    source = right;
    msgtype = RTAG;
    MPI_Recv(Q, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, source, msgtype,
              MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);}
```

I used:

```
if (left != NONE)  //boundary data exchange
     {MPI_Isend(Q, rows, MPI_DOUBLE, left,
                 RTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1);
        source = left;
        msgtype = LTAG;
        MPI_Irecv(Q, rows, MPI_DOUBLE, source,
                  msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req2);
 printf("boundary left done");
 MPI_Wait(&req1,&status);
 MPI_Wait(&req2,&status);
 }

     if (right != NONE)
     {
        MPI_Isend(Q, rows, MPI_DOUBLE, right,
                  LTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req3);
        source = right;
        msgtype = RTAG;
        MPI_Irecv(Q, rows, MPI_DOUBLE, source, msgtype,
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req4);
      printf("boundary right done");
      MPI_Wait(&req3,&status);
      MPI_Wait(&req4,&status);}
```

Thank you all for help!